# Advanced Techniques for Feature Detection in 3D Models with Overlapping Features Question:

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection

I'm working on feature detection within 3D models (given only points and lines forming areas), specifically focusing on extracting detailed information (e.g., corner coordinates) of complex features. Traditional programming methods have proven effective for simple shapes but fail with more intricate designs, particularly where features overlap or are in close proximity.

To address this, I've experimented with a neural network approach: training a keypoint detection model on multiple photographs taken from various angles around the model. I then apply 3D reconstruction techniques to merge these into a cohesive spatial understanding, aiming to identify and map the features back to the original 3D model based on the lines that define it. This method, using YoloV8 for the neural network, showed promise but struggled significantly with accuracy when features overlapped or were too close together.

I'm searching for alternative strategies or improvements to this approach that might enhance the precision of feature detection under these challenging conditions. Are there specific models, algorithms, or techniques known to perform better in distinguishing and accurately mapping complex, closely situated features in 3D models? Any guidance or references to similar work would be greatly appreciated.